# Plotting categorical predictor on x-axis with continuous moderator

Tags: r, plot, interaction

In R, what is the most straightforward way to plot an interaction between a categorical and a continuous predictor with the categorical predictor on the x-axis?

For some context, I have an experiment with three conditions (IV), a continuous DV and a continuous moderator. I have seen many examples of plots with the continuous predictor on the x-axis but very few the other way around. Is there a good way to do this in R?

Comment: This really isn't a specific enough question to be a programming question. There's no "right way" to plot data. It all depends on what is the story you are trying to tell. For general advice on plotting data, maybe [stats.se] is a better place to ask.

Comment: Check out `geom_violin` in `ggplot2` https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_violin.html

Comment: Or just boxplot, e.g. `boxplot(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Species)`